# Linq query to display unique set of names for current data set

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a linq query that is used to display the list of requests from multiple users.And a Requestor can have multple requests(So the grid can have same Requestor multiple times). Now i am creating a dropdown list with unique Requestor that are displayed on the grid.(issue is i am not getting the distinct list but getting all the Requestor multiple times). Below is the linq query i am unsing.Can anyone suggest with correct linq query.

```
  Dim rqstQry = From x In db.Request_vws _
                      Order By x.RequestID Descending _
                      Select x.RequestID,
                      Descr = x.Descr, _
                      RequestorName = String.Format("{0} {1}", x.FIRST_NAME, x.LAST_NAME), _
                      RelatedTask = GetTaskDescr(x.WorkID, x.TaskLabel, x.TaskDescr), _
                      RequestDescr = GetRequestDescr(x.RequestType), x.SubmitDttm, x.UpdatedDttm, _
                      x.ChangeDttm, _
                      x.MigrTimeStr, x.MigrApptTime, _
                      x.Requestor Ditinct
```

DataBind:

```
                      RequestorCB1.DataSource = rqstQry              
                      RequestorCB1.DataTextField = "Requestor"                        RequestorCB1.DataValueField = "REquestor"
                      RequestorCB1.DataBind()
```

Need distinct user in the dropdownlist

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: So why don't you query users instead of requests?

Comment: Updated question and answer can you check now it was requestor only not users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this by using the below query.

```
Dim rqstQry = (From x In db.Request_vws _
                  Order By x.RequestID Descending _
                  Select x.RequestID,
                  Descr = x.Descr, _
                  RequestorName = String.Format("{0} {1}", x.FIRST_NAME, x.LAST_NAME), _
                  RelatedTask = GetTaskDescr(x.WorkID, x.TaskLabel, x.TaskDescr), _
                  RequestDescr = GetRequestDescr(x.RequestType), x.SubmitDttm, x.UpdatedDttm, _
                  x.ChangeDttm, _
                  x.MigrTimeStr, x.MigrApptTime, _
                  x.Requestor). Distinct()


         Dim rqstQry2 = (From y In rqstQry _
                        Select y.Requestor, y.RequestorName).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

Put parentheses around the LINQ query and append `.Distinct()`

```
Dim rqstQry = (From x In db.Request_vws _
    Order By x.user
    Select x.user).Distinct()
```

If you are including Request stuff in the result, then you cannot get distinct users (as  Gert Arnold points out in his comment). Only include columns related to users.

If you still need information on requests then you must limit this information to one record per user. You would use a group by and use an aggregate in order to select a request (the first one, the last one etc.).

Comment: Ermm, `x.RequestID`... I don't think that Distinct is going to make any difference.

Comment: @oliver i tried what you said but it didnt make any difference

Comment: Have you tried after I removed all the columns but `x.user`.

Comment: Yes i tried it only returning all the Users but not distinct

Comment: Note that all the selected properties together are unique, not just a single one.